# How to fight BEAST vulnerability and maintain PFS for old clients?

Tags: openssl, ssl

Correct me if I'm wrong but BEAST is because of CBC in TLSv1.0, right? So to eliminate the threat of BEAST all CBC cipher suites which are SSLv3 or lower have to be disabled, right?

Lets jump into the real world example. See the [Qualys SSL Test for my test domain](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=dev5media.de&hideResults=on). You'll see that I have disabled SSLv3 (and lower of course) with protocols. To maintain some old clients which do not support TLSv1.1 and at the same time maintain Perfect Forward Secrecy for those clients I have to use some CBC cipher suites that came with SSLv3 or TLSv1.0.

Here are some samples of clients I have to maintain (with link to Qualys SSL Client Info site).

- [Java 7](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Java&version=7u25)
- [OpenSSL 0.9](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=OpenSSL&version=0.9.8y) (because of some routers)
- [IE 8 / XP](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=IE&version=8&platform=XP) (IE 6 / XP support is dropped)
- [Android 2.3](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=2.3.7)

Here is my OpenSSL 1.0.1e cipher suite configuration:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:-DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
```

**Does anybody see a solution to fix BEAST and maintain Client/PFS?** I only see max. TLSv1.0 and CBC only cipher suites on the client side.

To catch up with Michael Hampton: Yes, **RC4 is not a solution**. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Could someone add `BEAST` and `PFS` tags, please?

Comment: You don't want to do this. BEAST isn't a significant threat anymore, and mitigating it requires enabling RC4, which _is_ considered weak and is getting weaker.

Comment: Note that when the Qualys indicates a configuration failure, it doesn't mean the configuration can't connect to the server. The results for [one of my test servers](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=homelinuxbox.com&hideResults=on) indicates 'IE 11 / Win 7  R Protocol or cipher suite mismatch', but I can actually load the site with the failed configuration. Note that I'm mostly a cargo cult admin when it comes to OpenSSL, but I wanted to advise that failure on Qualys doesn't mean the site won't load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, this can't be done, and doesn't need to be done anyway.

BEAST is no longer considered a serious threat, as client-side patches have been available for affected platforms for years now (even for XP!), and server-side mitigation requires RC4, which is now considered too weak to be secure and only makes things worse.